# How do I set and Account object to an opportunity ID

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I have a trigger which calls a class when an opportunity's status changes to "Closed Won".

```
trigger opptConversion on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
        if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            sendEnvelope se = new sendEnvelope(opp);
            se.sendEnvelopeMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

The sendEnvelope class:

```
public class sendEnvelope {
  
   Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(); 

   public sendEnvelope(Opportunity opp) {
        this.opportunity = opp; 
   }
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendEnvelopeMethod() {
 
Account myAccount = opportunity.AccountId;
```

Normally I use `Account myAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test' LIMIT 1];`
But now Im trying to set the Account object to the passed in OpportunityId from the trigger.

Ive tried `Account myAccount = opportunity.AccountId;` but this gives Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to Account

Ive also tried `Account myAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE AccountId = opportunity.AccountId LIMIT 1];`

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- Using the sobject name as a variable name (`Opprotunity opportunity`) appears to cause some confusion in the compiler, you should rename that variable
- `AccountId` is a field of type `Id`, it points to an Account, but it is itself not an `Account`
- The way you're trying to pass data, using an instance variable doesn't work with `@future` methods (you can't access instance variables from a static method, and a `@future` annotated method must be a static method)

Setting aside the concerns about being bulk friendly (we're limited to 50 @future calls per transaction), what you probably want to do to get this working is to have your @future method accept an `AccountId` argument. E.g. `public static void sendEnvelopeMethod(Id accountId)`

If you just need to update the Account specified by that Id based on data you get from a callout, you don't need to query for the Account at all. We can use the SObject constructor to set the Id, and an Id is all we need to perform an update.

```java
// This is pseudocode

Account myAcc = new Account(Id = passedInAccId);
// callout stuff here
myAcc.Field = calloutResult.value;

update myAcc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside ur future method u could use something like this

```
@future
public static void sendEnvelopeMethod(Id accId) {
 List<Account> acclst=[select id, name from Account where id=:accId];
update acclst;
} 
Inside your trigger use below code to update the parent Account record. 
trigger opptConversion on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
        if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            sendEnvelope.sendEnvelopeMethod(opp.AccountId);
        }
    }
}
```

Please do make sure to check all the governor limit considerations.